# Repeat something for 500 seconds . . . (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, browser

So I have this script that fills out certain forms through a web page on the WebBrowser tool. It needs to fill out these forms for 500 seconds, and then do whatever I specify it to do. What can I make to make a script run for 500 seconds on visual basic?

Comment: That is what `Timers` were designed for.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Timer` control, like this:

- Drag and drop a `Timer` control from the toolbox onto your form.
- Set the interval for the timer for 500 seconds (500,000 milliseconds).
- Enable the timer.
- Start the timer.
- Create method to execute when the timer finishes.

Assuming you are doing this in response to a button click, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 500000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimerEventProcessor(myObject As Object, ByVal myEventArgs As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()

    ' Do something to indicate the timer is up, message, etc. or start a new timer, etc. 
End Sub
```